# How can I create a short command to launch a browser (Internet Explorer is what I'll use) running as another account

Tags: windows, cmd, doskey

I would like to start Internet Explorer as a different user through a command line alias. I liked the approach of using an AutoRun registry setting to call an environment setting script.

So I have an AutoRun registry key (REG_SZ) setup for HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor to execute an env.cmd file. The env.cmd file has one line in it:
    **DOSKEY ieas=runas /user:user /netonly "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"**

My question is whether there a way to write the DOSKEY command in the env.cmd file so that I can pass in the user name when I invoke **ieas**? I want to type: 
    **ieas MyDomain\SomeUser**
and have runas use MyDomain\SomeUser for the /user variable and prompt me for the specified account's password.

Comment: `DOSKEY ieas=runas /user:$1 /netonly "C:\...\iexplore.exe"` as per `doskey /?` (use full path to `iexplore.exe`, of course)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I tried $* as well, but $1 is more appropriate for the use intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DOSKEY ieas=runas /user:$1 /netonly "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

As per `doskey /?`:

```
Edits command lines, recalls Windows commands, and creates macros.

DOSKEY [/REINSTALL] [/LISTSIZE=size] [/MACROS[:ALL | :exename]]
  [/HISTORY] [/INSERT | /OVERSTRIKE] [/EXENAME=exename] [/MACROFILE=filename]
  [macroname=[text]]
...
  macroname           Specifies a name for a macro you create.
  text                Specifies commands you want to record.
...

The following are some special codes in Doskey macro definitions:
$T     Command separator.  Allows multiple commands in a macro.
$1-$9  Batch parameters.  Equivalent to %1-%9 in batch programs.
$*     Symbol replaced by everything following macro name on command line.
```